# Can fast, optimized server calls collapse a server?

Tags: optimization, server-side

I've followed a series of optimizations to make our APIs faster. We microoptimized a lot of PHP code to faster, native methods, we unset variables where they were not being used anymore, and basically improved anything that could be improved in the server code (MySQL queries were left untouched).

We improved the time a request takes by about 10%, everything works the same and passes the tests, but we noticed that the servers started stacking and our cores load average went from roughly 0.3 to 2.5

The MySQL usage also raised from 10 to 25 concurrent connections, which essentially should mean that more concurrent users can be using the API.

*Could it be that optimizing the server side code killed the server?*

Comment: By optimizing your API calls, you have changed the execution profile of your service/app.  That isn't always for the better.  Possibly you have made the (un-optimized) MySQL pieces a larger part of the execution and therefore created a larger overall load.  Any major optimization effort really needs to be tested to make sure you didn't just move the problem somewhere else or create a new problem.

Comment: @cdkMoose Indeed, the server requests were taking a lot because we were doing pretty heavy queries and all of them started stacking on top of others. We tried to do the process the other way around (first optimizing the MySQL, testing it and then improving the php parts) and everything started going smoothly. If you add this as an answer, I can just accept it!

Comment: Where I/O was previously a bottleneck (load < 1, threads waiting), now CPU is a bottleneck (load > 1 per CPU). The real question is, how did your _throughput_ and _average call latency_ change? Without these numbers, it's hard to tell if the optimization made sense at all.

Comment: @9000 Sadly the tools we had were pretty limited (we couldn't install monitoring systems). We could only track the average time a request takes to be processed, the amount of memory used by PHP and the overall server load

Comment: @Korcholis: this should be enough. You can see how many requests the server can process in a few minutes of intense (simulated) load: this is throughput. You can see how long it takes for one request to complete; this is latency. The former should grow, the latter shrink. (Also, you should be able to decide which of the two is more important for you.)

Comment: @9000 hmmm, well, both are important! But of course, life is full of decisions. To me, after looking at the numbers, it simply looks like the MySQL server was having a bad time, but I can't contrast it with numbers. In some cases, it looked like there were too many accesses from one single script, and after another one wanted to do the same, the DB was locked and it had to wait for too much, stacking requests, and collapsing the server. We reduced the latency (I'm taking your word!), but something that was magically balanced before (too much time for PHP and DB) was now out of control.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By optimizing your API calls, you have changed the execution profile of your service/app. That isn't always for the better. Possibly you have made the (un-optimized) MySQL pieces a larger part of the execution and therefore created a larger overall load. Any major optimization effort really needs to be tested to make sure you didn't just move the problem somewhere else or create a new problem.

In a multi-tiered application, changes in one layer can have drastic impacts on other layers.  When attempting to optimize, you need to have a coordinated effort across layers.